# Help with complex logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

For real $x$ what does $-\ln(1-e^{2\pi i x})$ equal so that it agrees with the series expansion, how would I find the real and imaginary parts.
$$-\ln(1-e^{2\pi ix})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi i n x}}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

By [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula),
$$
1-e^{2\pi ix}=1-\cos(2\pi x)-i\sin(2\pi x)
$$
Using [$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value), we get
$$
\begin{align}
&-\log(1-e^{2\pi ix})\\
=&-\frac12\log\left((1-\cos(2\pi x))^2+\sin^2(2\pi x)\right)-i\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-\sin(2\pi x)}{1-\cos(2\pi x)}\right)\\
=&-\frac12\log\left(2-2\cos(2\pi x)\right)+i\tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x))\\
=&-\frac12\log\left(4\sin^2(\pi x)\right)+i\tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x))\\
=&-\log\left(2|\sin(\pi x)|\right)+i\tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x))\\
\end{align}
$$
for all $x$. However, for $x\in\left(-\tfrac12,+\tfrac12\right)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x))&=\frac\pi2\mathrm{sgn}(x)-\pi x
\end{align}
$$
and $-\log(1-e^{2\pi ix})$ has period $1$.

The series converges, for $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, by the [Dirichlet Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).